# Returning list of strings in JpaRepository using @Query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity Lecture that contains a List<String> lectureFileNames. I want to extract that list by a lecture id. This is my query:

```
@Query("SELECT lecture.lectureFileNames FROM Lecture lecture WHERE lecture.id = :lectureId")
List<String> getLectureFiles(@Param("lectureId") Long id);
```

The problem is that Hibernate throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity [SELECT lecture.lectureFileNames FROM x.y.z.model.Lecture lecture WHERE lecture.id = :lectureId]
```

I know that I can extract the value of a field using @Query but right now I have no idea why this doesn't work.

Comment: Have you annotated the class with @Entity annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join the collection:

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Lecture lecture JOIN lecture.lectureFileNames f WHERE lecture.id = :lectureId")
List<String> getLectureFiles(@Param("lectureId") Long id);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to be able to retrieve the elements of a query. That of projection using an interface. Look at this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections